# how to plot a graph with mpmath in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, mpmath, interval-arithmetic

I need to simulate several models with interval arithmetic, the most viable package I found was: mpmath. However I am having problems with plotting the graphics. I did an initial test before applying it to the models. can anybody help me?

- Another problem is that I always need a for to create my interval variable and this greatly increases the computational cost. Would there be another alternative?

This my code:

```
import mpmath as mp
import math as mt
from mpmath import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iv.dps = 10
iv.pretty = True
X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10, endpoint=True)
a=iv.mpf(X[1])

b=[]
for k in range(len(X)):
    b = np.append(b,iv.mpf(X[k]) )
C=[]
for k in range(len(X)):
    C = np.append(C, iv.sin(b[k]))
print(C)
```

- I need to plot the sin, and mp.plot doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.01)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```